# Out of Bound Error at arraylist in prefix average algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm

java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: error occurs when adding a single value to the first arrayList, in order to perform prefix averages as such that the value of A is computed by

id like to note that using arrays in this algorithm worked but when trying to switch to an arraylist does the issue occur.
Array A Contents of A[i]

```
A[0]     (X[0])/1
A[1]     (X[0]+X[1])/2
A[2]     (X[0]+X[1]+X[2])/3
A[3]     (X[0]+X[1]+X[2]+X[3])/4
A[4]     (X[0]+X[1]+X[2]+X[3]+X[4])/5
A[5]     (X[0]+X[1]+X[2]+X[3]+X[4]+X[5])/6
A[6]     (X[0]+X[1]+X[2]+X[3]+X[4]+X[5]+X[6])/7
A[7]     (X[0]+X[1]+X[2]+X[3]+X[4]+X[5]+X[6]+X[7])/8
A[8]     (X[0]+X[1]+X[2]+X[3]+X[4]+X[5]+X[6]+X[7]+X[8])/9
A[9]     (X[0]+X[1]+X[2]+X[3]+X[4]+X[5]+X[6]+X[7]+X[8]+X[9])/10
```

started off with a.get(i) = s/(i+1); that didn't help. then tried setting the contents of a[i] with the out come of s/(i+1) still no avail

```
public class prefixAverage{
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        ArrayList <Float> X = new ArrayList <Float>();
        X.add(9f);

        System.out.print(PrefixAverage(X));
    }

    public static ArrayList<Float> PrefixAverage(ArrayList<Float> X){
        ArrayList <Float> a = new ArrayList <Float>();
        float s = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i<= X.size()-1;i++) {
            s = s +X.get(i);
            a.set(i,s/(i+1));
            System.out.print(a.get(i)+", ");
        }
        return a;
    }
}
```

I am expecting an increasing size average as the index of A increase

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`List::set` sets an *existing* element to a new value. In your case, `a` is an empty list so you can't use that method (or you get an exception).

You probably meant to use `a.add(i, value)` instead, which will insert an element at the given index (and expand the list by one item).

In your case, you are inserting at index 0, then 1 etc., so you can simply use `a.add(value)`.